# Show that the subset of $\mathbb{R} ^3$ is closed and not compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Let $X$ = $\mathbb{R} ^3$ with its standard distance function. Standard distance function is $d(x,y) =||x -y||$.
> Prove that the subset $E$ = $\{ (x,y,z) \in {\mathbb{R}} ^3 \mid z \ge 0 \}$ $\subset$ $X$ is closed and not open.

My attempt:
Take some $e \in E$ such that $e = (x, y, z)$ such that $z \ge 0$.
Then for any $\epsilon >0$, some $(x', y', z')$ will be in $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $e$ if:
$(x'-x)^2 +(y'-y)^2 +(z'-z)^2 < \epsilon ^2$
Then take:
$(z'-z)^2 < \epsilon ^2$. Let $z>0$ and $\epsilon = z/2$
$|z'-z|<\epsilon$.
$-\epsilon<z' - z<\epsilon$
$z-\epsilon<z'<z+\epsilon$
$z-\frac{z}{2}<z'<z+\frac{z}{2}$ , since $\epsilon = z/2$
thus $\frac{z}{2}<z'<\frac{3z}{2}$ and it follows that $z'>0$ since $z>0$.

With the proof above I only showed that the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $e$ contains points from $E$ which should mean that $E$ contains its limit points. However, I need to show that the points outside of E are not limit points to conclude that the $E$ is indeed closed. Can someone provide a hint or an idea?

I also need to show that $E$ is not compact. Any idea how to do that would also be really helpful.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's much easier to do with sequences, if you are familiar with this. If a sequence of points in $E$ converges, it's easy to prove the limit also must be in $E$. This means $E$ is closed. It's clearly not compact because it's not bounded.

Comment: It is not compact because it is bout bounded. It is closed since $E$ is the preimmage of a closed set under a continuous function: $p(x,y,z)=z$ is continuous, $E=p^{-1}([0,\infty)$.

Comment: You can also shoe that $E^c$ is open with your neighborhood argument: Take $(x,y,z)\in E^c$, so that $z<0$. Let $\varepsilon =|z|/2$; The ball $B((x,y,z):|z|/2)$ is fully contained in $E^c$; hence $E^c$ is open and by definition, its complement $E$ is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general way to show that a set is closed is to show that its complement is open.  Assume $P=(x_0, y_0, z_0) \notin E$.  Choose $\varepsilon = \dfrac{\vert z_0 \vert}{2}$.  Then it's easy to show that $B(P, \varepsilon) \cap E = \varnothing$.  That means $\Bbb R^3 \setminus E$ is open (because any point outside of $E$ is included in an open ball that's also outside of $E$), so $E$ must be closed.  Here, I'm using $B(P, \varepsilon)$ to designate the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $P$.

To show that no unbounded set (such as $E$) can be compact, just note that $\{ B((0, 0, 0), n) \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ is an open cover of all of $\Bbb R^3$, and therefore of any subset of $\Bbb R^3$, but no finite subset of this open cover can cover any unbounded set.

Answer (score 2):

Some standard arguments for quick judgments(may be difficult!)

1. $A\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ is compact iff closed and bounded.
2. $\pi_z:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by $\pi_z((x, y, z))=z$ is continuous.
   $\\$The given set $E=\pi_z^{-1}\{[0,\infty) \}$
3. $\{(0, 0,n):n\in\Bbb{N}\}\subset E$ and $\Bbb{N}$ is unbounded above.
4. $\Bbb{R}^3$ is connected i.e $A\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ open and closed implies $A=\emptyset$ or $A=\Bbb{R}^3$

Comment: (+1) + OP, if you don't know connectedness, you can replace 4 (to prove that the closed subset $E$ is not open) by: $O:=(0,0,0)\in E$ but $E$ contains no open ball $B(O,r)$ ($r>0$). And in 1 (used together with 3 to prove that $E$ is not compact) you only need: if a metric space is compact then it is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of proving that $E$ is closed is to consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R^3&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&(x,y,z)&\mapsto&z.\end{array}$$Since $f$ is continuous and $[0,\infty)$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$, $f^{-1}\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr)$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$. But $E=f^{-1}\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr)$.

And $E$ is not compact since it is unbounded.